# How to create a multiple layer perceptron with layers of specific sizes in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to recreate a model based on its description. The model is described as a "10 layers of size 500 ... 10". From my understanding, the size refers to the number of hidden units, which I could customize using model.add(dense)

My code looks like this:

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape)
model.add(Dense(500, activation = 'relu')) 
... 
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))
```

However, it is yielding a very low accuracy rate (about 20% lower than what I was supposed to get).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should definitely elaborate more of the problem you are facing. When you say accuracy is lesser by 20%, compared to what? Is only increasing accuracy your concern? You should add a complete code snippet so that you can get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

There may be quite a lot of reasons for this. As I understand you try to repeat someone's results, and all you know is the architecture. Your keras architecture seems correct, but you should also take into account:

1. Data - did the authors used data augmentation?
2. Regularizations, such as dropout, L1, L2, batch normalization - that can significantly influence your results.
3. Other hyper-parameters, like optimizer, batch size etc. Did you do a grid/random search of those?

If you took all this into account, provide us with more complete training code, so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the point right based on the title of the question, in your code you are not making multi layer perceptron. You have tried to make somehow a convolutional network. In MLPs you just have to stack dense layers. Do something like the following code snippet which stacks just dense layers:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))
```